# Only 4 cores working out of 8

Tags: android, cpu-cores

I have bought a new phone, but looking in cpu-z, only 4 cores are active, out of 8. The CPU chipset is HiSilicon Kirin 620 and I have read that other set of 4 cores kick in when needed, is this true? Other set of 4 CPU shows as stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is true and also sometimes few cores(low performance cores) are designed to be used in Saver Mode when battery is less..